# How to combine multidimensional array on basis of keys

Tags: php

```
Hi I have two arrays in my controller function following, I want final array with merged of     matched keys of both arrays to use further it as flowing:

//Array1
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
            [LedgerID] => 573c321e6e3dcec3228b4567
            [LedgerName] => Purchase1
            [PanITNO] => ITR00123
            [dateOfPayment] => 08-Dec-2015
            [totalAmountPaid] => 9800
            [tdsRate] => 2
            [totalDudections] => 10000
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
        [LedgerName] => Development Fund
        [PanITNO] => dfdsfdsf
        [dateOfPayment] => 13-Jan-2016
        [totalAmountPaid] => 18000
        [tdsRate] => 10
        [totalDudections] => 20000
    )
```

)
     //Array2

```
    Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
           [Amountdeposited] => 200
           [dateOfDeposited] => 25-Feb-2016
           [challaNumber] => 1234
     )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [Amountdeposited] => 2000
        [dateOfDeposited] => 25-Feb-2016
        [challaNumber] => 1234
       )

) 
I want output like following Merged matched keys of both arrays into one final array:
array(
[0] => Array
   (
        [LedgerID] => 573c321e6e3dcec3228b4567
        [LedgerName] => Purchase1
        [PanITNO] => ITR00123
        [dateOfPayment] => 08-Dec-2015
        [totalAmountPaid] => 9800
        [tdsRate] => 2
        [totalDudections] => 10000,
        [Amountdeposited] => 200
        [dateOfDeposited] => 25-Feb-2016
        [challaNumber] => 1234

    )
[1] => Array
   (
        [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
        [LedgerName] => Development Fund
        [PanITNO] => dfdsfdsf
        [dateOfPayment] => 13-Jan-2016
        [totalAmountPaid] => 18000
        [tdsRate] => 10
        [totalDudections] => 20000,
        [Amountdeposited] => 2000
        [dateOfDeposited] => 25-Feb-2016
        [challaNumber] => 1234

    )
```

)
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result, 
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result,
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result,
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result,
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result,
How to combine key's of both arrays to get desired result,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can search for this solution, there are a lots of solution of it.

Comment: Yes, Custom I can do it but I am not sure is there any php function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
 $i=0;
        $datas=array();
        foreach($array1 as $k=>$v)
        {
         $v['Amountdeposited'] = $array2[$i]['Amountdeposited'] ;
         $v['dateOfDeposited'] = $array2[$i]['dateOfDeposited'] ;
         $v['challaNumber']    = $array2[$i]['challaNumber'] ;
         $i++;
         $datas[$k]=$v;
        }

    print_r($datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

1)

```
 $out = array();
 foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
      $out[] = array_merge((array)$value,(array)$array2[$key]);
 }
 print_r($out)
```

2) `array_replace_recursive` (Used only when array has not same key other wise this function replace the value of $array key to $array2 key value )

```
print_r(array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2));
```